# Expected values of a dice game with a 30-sided die and a 20-sided die.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Two people, $A$ and $B$, have a $30$-sided and $20$-sided die, respectively. Each rolls their die, and the person with the highest roll wins. ($B$ also wins in the event of a tie.) The loser pays the winner the value on the winner's die.

**Question:**

1. What is expected value for player $A$?
2. How does the expected value of the game for player $A$ change when player $B$ can re-roll?
3. How much is it worth for player $A$ to get a re-roll in this scenario, where player $B$ can have the re-roll?
4. If you remove player $A$ re-roll. How many re-rolls does player $B$ need in order for him to be a favorite in the game?

I took the average score for player $A$ to be $15.5$ and for player $B$ to be $10.5$. I am assuming this to be expected return for player $A$ so $15.5 - 10.5 = 5$. We also need to take into account when $X = Y$ when $A$ loses to $B$ on draw so $5 - (7/20) = 4.65$.

What I do not understand is how to factor in for when player $B$ can re-roll. I understand that $B$ would re-roll if he gets a value $< 10.5$ which happens $\frac 12$ of the time. Nor can I seem to grasp how to set up the  follow-up questions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22885/discussion-on-question-by-vmo-person-a-has-30-sided-die-and-person-b-has-20-side).

Answer (score 4):

### 1. What is the expected value for player $A$?

Let $A, B$ be the players' rolls and $W$ be player $A$'s winnings. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
\mathbb{E}W &=
\mathbb{E}[W|A \leq 20]\cdot\mathbb{P}\{A \leq 20\} 
\ +\ 
\mathbb{E}[W|A > 20]\cdot\mathbb{P}\{A > 20\}
\end{align}
$$
just by simply conditioning on the event $\{A \leq 20\}$ so far.

1. Now $\mathbb{E}[W|A \leq 20]$ would be zero if not for the fact that ties are settled in player $B$'s favor:
   $$
      \mathbb{E}[W|A \leq 20]
      = -\frac{1+20}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{20}
      $$
   as ties happen with probability $\frac{1}{20}$ and player $B$ wins $\frac{1+20}{2}$ per tie, on average.
2. When $A > 20$, player $A$ always wins, and wins
   $$
      \mathbb{E}[W|A > 20]
      = \frac{21+30}{2}
      $$
   on average.

Putting it all together,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}W
&= -\frac{21}{40}\frac{2}{3} + \frac{51}{2}\frac{1}{3} \\
&= \frac{163}{20}\\
&= 8.15
\end{align}
$$
as was derived in previous answers. So far so good.

### 2. How does the expected value of the game for player $A$ change when player $B$ can re-roll?

Here the wording becomes rather more vague. Nonetheless I believe both previous answers misinterpret the problem statement. Allowing player $B$ a re-roll does **not** mean $B$ chooses the maximum of two rolls: that would be worded as "player $B$ is allowed the greater of two rolls". Allowing player $B$ a re-roll means that if player $B$ is unhappy with her first roll she may substitute it with a second roll, which may turn out to be less than her first. The ambiguity is in whether the re-roll is offered *before* or *after* player $B$ has seen player $A$'s roll. I consider only the first case, as it permits us to offer numbers instead of functions (of  player $A$'s roll) as answers to this question, and to question 4.

Clearly, player $B$ will re-roll after rolling $b$ or less iff
$$
\tag{2}
\mathbb{E}[W|B=b] > \mathbb{E}[W] = 8.15
$$
as she wishes to *minimize* $W$.
At this point we may as well calculate:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[W|B=b] &=
\mathbb{E}[W|B=b, A \leq b]\cdot\mathbb{P}\{A \leq b\} 
\ +\ 
\mathbb{E}[W|B=b, A > b]\cdot\mathbb{P}\{A > b\} \\
&=-b\frac{b}{30}+\frac{(b+1)+30}{2}\frac{30-b}{30} \\
&= \frac{-3b^2-b+930}{60}.
\end{align}
$$
Let $b^*$ be the maximum $b$ such that inequality $(2)$ holds.
(I found $b^* = 11$. Is there a faster, less error-prone method of calculating this part?)

Let $W_1$ be the value of the game when player $B$ can re-roll. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[W_1] &=
\mathbb{E}W + \frac{b^*}{20}\big(\mathbb{E}W - \mathbb{E}[W|B \leq b^*]\big)\\
\end{align}
as we modify the old $\mathbb{E}W$ by adding the effect of the re-roll. I express it in this way because
$$\mathbb{E}[W|B \leq b^*]$$
is easy to calculate quickly as it expands just like equation $(1)$ does, by pretending player $B$ is rolling a $b^*$-sided die.

Answer (score 3):

Letting $D_k$ be the random value of a fair $k$-sided dice roll, the probability that $A$ will win is: 
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(D_{30}>D_{20}) & = \sum_{b=1}^{20} \mathsf P(D_{20}=b)\; \mathsf P(D_{30}>b)
\\ & = \frac{1}{20}\sum_{b=1}^{20}\left(1- \frac{b}{30}\right)
\\ & =\frac{13}{20}
\end{align}$$

Allowing a reroll effectively means taking the maximum result of two rolls ($D_{20,1}, D_{20,2}$), so then the probability of A winning is:
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(D_{30}>\max(D_{20,1}, D_{20,2})) & =\frac{10}{30} + \sum_{a=1}^{20} \mathsf P(D_{30}=a)\;\mathsf P(D_{20,1}< a)\;\mathsf P(D_{20,2}< a)
\\ & = \frac{10}{30} + \frac{1}{30}\sum_{a=1}^{20} \left(\frac {a-1} {20}\right)^2
\\ & = \frac{647}{1200}
\end{align}$$

From these probabilities you can chocolate the expected returns.

Can you complete the rest?

Comment: Chocolate the expected returns? :P

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\frac{10}{30}$ - related to the probability that $A$ rolls $21-30$?

Comment: Graham Kemp. I love chocolate. Thanks for using this word in context of math. I´m curious about the definition of it.

Comment: One of my favorite chocolate is [Ritter Sport Nugat](https://eatexploreetc.com/review-nugat-chocolate-bar-ritter-sport/)

Comment: "Allowing a reroll effectively means taking the maximum result of two rolls" -- Doesn't this assume that B's result that is used for comparing purposes is the maximum of the 2 rolls? I believe this question assumes that if B rolls again, then the 2nd roll is used for comparison purposes.

Comment: You reroll when the first d20 result is less than the d30.  If it is more, use that, else if it less, try the other. The "Success" event occurs when the d30 result is greater than either the first or the second d20 roll. Thus you are *effectively* comparing the maximum of two d20 rolls to the d30 result. @Iamanon

Answer (score 1):

The expected return for $A$ is the following sum, where $X_a$ is the roll for $A$ and $X_b$ is the roll for $B$:$$\sum_{h=1}^{30} \left(hP(X_a=h)P(X_b<h) - hP(X_a\leq h)P(X_b=h)\right)\tag{1}$$

This is: $$\sum_{h=1}^{20} h\left(\frac{1}{30}\frac{h-1}{20} -\frac{h}{30}\frac{1}{20}\right) + \sum_{h=21}^{30}\frac{h}{30}$$

(I used $h$ because it is the highest value rolled.)

I get $8.15$ as the result, but I could have failed in the algebra somewhere.

The formula is the same as (1) when $B$ getting two rolls, but the variable $X_b$ is different - it is the maximum value of two rolls. This is going to be more complicated. Let $X_{b,2}$ be the value of the maximum of two rolls of the $20$-sided die. Then $P(X_{b,2}=h)=\frac{2h+1}{20^2}$ for $h\leq 20$ and zero otherwise, and $P(X_{b,2}<h)=\frac{(h-1)^2}{20^2}$ for $h\leq 20$ and $1$ for $h>20$. Lots of ugly algebra.

In general, if $X_{b,k}$ is the maximum when rolling the die $k$ times, then $$P(X_{b,k}<h) = \begin{cases}\frac{(h-1)^k}{20^k}&h\leq 20\\
1&h>20
\end{cases} $$

and:

$$P(X_{b,k}=h)=\begin{cases}
\frac{h^k-(h-1)^k}{20^k}&h\leq 20\\
0&h>20\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and insight. I can see now that I greatly over simplified the initial expected value calculation attempt.

Comment: I got that B needs to be able to re-roll $6$ times to have the advantage. But I had to use a computer.

Comment: Hi, I have been learning how you derived your equations since yesterday. I had a question on the second part of the equation. May I ask why you decided to let X_b, 2 to be the value of the maximum of two rolls? If I am recalling expectation correctly, shouldn't B want to re-roll if his roll is < 10.5 and stop if it is greater? Or am I incorrectly understanding expectation because B is at a disadvantage (if I may call it that) because his die can only go up to 20.

Comment: At what number would player B think to himself that it is better to re-roll? If player A can re-roll given B can re-roll, what additional benefit (upside) is it to A?