# 20 Sided vs 30 Sided Dice Game

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, game-theory

Alice and Bob have fair
30
sided and
20
sided dice, respectively. Alice rolls her die one time. However, Bob can roll his die twice and keep the maximum of the two values. In the event of a tie, Bob is the winner. Find the probability Alice is the winner.

My approach was as follows. 1/3 of the time, Alice gets a value between 21 and 30, so she wins automatically. 2/3 of the time, Alice's value is between 1 and 20. In this case, she wins in the event when her roll is strictly greater than both of Bob's rolls. The probability of Alice's roll being strictly greater is $\frac{(20^2-20)/2}{20^2}$ =$\frac{190}{400}$. The reasoning here is that there are 400 combinations, and 20 of these are times when Alice's and Bob's rolls are equal, in which case Alice loses. Hence, my total probability works out to be:

P = $\frac{1}{3}(1) + \frac{2}{3}(\frac{190}{400})^2$

This answer is wrong, and I suspect it is due to my probability of Alice's roll being strictly greater than both Bob's rolls.

Comment: You need to compute the probability, $p_i$ that Bob gets an $i$.  Hint:  it's a lot easier to compute the probability that Bob gets $≤i$ and from that you can read off what you need.

Comment: Note:  this is *extremely* similar to [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753108/20-and-30-sided-dice-game)

Comment: If Alice has a roll and Bob has two rolls, I would expect the denominator to be  $20^3 =8000$ if you are going to use your $\frac23$ term rather than $400$ (or $30 \times 20 \times 20 =12000$ if you do not use that term)

Comment: @3.14 The questions are different. The opportunity to re-roll (thereby giving up the opportunity to use the result of the first roll) is not the same as rolling twice and being able to use the higher of the two rolls.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208182/probability-interview-question-brain-teaser/2208213#2208213).

Comment: I think one thing that is unclear in your attempt is this: "she wins in the event when her roll is strictly greater than both of Bob's rolls. The probability of Alice's roll being strictly greater is ... ." Some of us (including myself) read the second sentence as a statement about the same event described in the first sentence, that is, the probability that Alice's single roll is greater than both of Bob's. But now I think you mean the probability that Alice's roll is greater than **one** of Bob's rolls. Can you please edit the question to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Forming cases,

1.if Alice get $1$ then Bob wons in any case.

2.if Alice get $2$ then Bob wons in any case other than droping $(1,1)$.

3.if Alice get $3$ then Bob wons in any case other than droping $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)$.

4.if Alice get $4$ then Bob wons in any case other than combinations of $1,2,3$ comes in two dice roll i.e. $3^2$ combinations.

$........$

20.if Alice get $20$ then Bob wons in any case other than combinations of $1,2,3,...,19$ comes in two dice roll i.e. $19^2$ combinations.

21.if Alice get $21,22,23,24,...,30$ then Bob lost.

As fiar dices, Every posible outcomes of Alice's dice is $\frac{1}{30}$.

Bob's winning probability
$$
\begin{aligned}
&= \frac{1}{30}  \cdot  \frac{400-0}{400}  + \frac{1}{30}  \cdot  \frac{400-1^2}{400}+\frac{1}{30}  \cdot  \frac{400-2^2}{400}+....+\frac{1}{30}  \cdot  \frac{400-19^2}{400} \\
&= \frac{1}{30} \left[\frac{20 \cdot 400 - (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \ldots + 19^2)}{400}\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{30} \left[20 - \frac{19 \cdot 20 \cdot (19 \cdot 2 + 1)}{400 \cdot 6}\right] \\
&= \frac{553}{1200}
\end{aligned}
$$

So, Alice's wining probability$$=1- \frac{553}{1200} =\bbox[10px, border: 2px solid black]{\frac{647}{1200}}$$

Proof of validitiy, (Python code for $10000$ trials.)

```
import random as r

def calculate_probability():
    # Initialize variables
    alice_wins = 0
    n = 10000

    for _ in range(n):
        # Calculate Alice rolling a specific value
        alice_roll = r.randint(1, 31)
        bob_roll = max(r.randint(1, 21), r.randint(1, 21))

        if alice_roll > bob_roll:
            alice_wins += 1

    # Return the probability that Alice is the winner
    return alice_wins / n

# Calculate and print the probability
probability = calculate_probability()
print(f"The probability that Alice is the winner is approximately {probability:.4f}")

#Output:The probability that Alice is the winner is approximately 0.5323
#Which good approximate of my answer for 10000 trials.
```