# Expected Value Question 30 sided/20 sided die solution Issue

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, problem-solving, dice

I recently saw a problem wherein player $A$ is given a $30$ sided die, player $B$ is given a 20 sided die, and they both simultaneously roll and whoever gets the higher outcome wins that dollar amount. If they draw then player B wins. Calculate the expected value for player $A$.

I have seen the solution claimed to be $8.15$ but in the original solution for the problem I have seen claimed to be $10.2$. I got 10.2 and I am uncertain as to where the mistake in my solution is assuming there is one.

Let $Z$ be the random variable that represents the amount that is won or lost by player A, $X$ be the random variable that represents the dice roll of player A, and $Y$ the random variable that represents the dice roll of player B.

By definition, we want to calculate $$\mathbb{E}[Z] = \sum_{z \in Range(Z)}z\mathbb{P}(Z = z)$$

Assume we are player A. Here note that by the rules of the game we can lose what our opponent rolls, or we can win what we roll. Thus we see that we can lose anywhere from $20, 19, ..., 1$ dollars. Also observe that we cannot win $1$ dollar as our opponent cannot roll a smaller value and can only tie this value. Therefore the number of dollars we can win are anywhere from $2, 3, ..., 30$ dollars. Our sum above becomes:

$$\sum_{z \in Range(Z)}z\mathbb{P}(Z = z) = \sum_{j=2}^{30}j \mathbb{P}(Z=j) - \sum_{i=1}^{20}i\mathbb{P}(Z=-i)$$

Now $\mathbb{P}(Z = j) = \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\mathbb{P}(X= j, Y = i) = \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\mathbb{P}(X=j)\mathbb{P}(Y=i) = \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{1}{600} = \frac{j-1}{600}$.

Similarly: $\mathbb{P}(Z=-i) = \sum_{j=1}^i\mathbb{P}(X=j)\mathbb{P}(Y=i) = \frac{i}{600}$

substituting these expressions into the expected value definition above we obtain:

$$\sum_{j=2}^{30}\frac{j(j-1)}{600} - \sum_{i=1}^{20}\frac{i^2}{600}$$

Using the formulas: $\sum_{k=1}^nk = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}, \sum_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$, factoring out $\frac{1}{600}$ we get:

$$\frac{1}{600}(\frac{1}{6}(30)(31)(61) - 1 -\frac{1}{2}(30)(31) + 1 - \frac{1}{6}(20)(21)(41)) = 15.78533 -.775-4.7833$$

Which gives me $10.2$

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236805/expected-values-of-a-dice-game-with-a-30-sided-die-and-a-20-sided-die) is a duplicate, which claims the $8.15$ result.

Comment: Note:  there appears to be some confusion regarding the rules.  In the version I linked to, the loser must pay the winner.  It's different if the money simply comes out of some neutral pool.

Comment: @lulu this could potentially be where my mistake lies then, but what I fail to see is how that assumption effects the calculation. In this case we are just calculating expected value of one turn, and so I'm uncertain of how the definition of expected value or the calculation would change in this instance.

Comment: I have not studied your computation, but I note that your description of the rules doesn't indicate where the money comes from.  It clearly makes a difference!  If $A$ rolls a $5$ and $B$ rolls a $10$, does $A$ have a loss of $10$ or no loss at all?    Again, the version I linked to clearly says that, in my scenario, $A$ would have a loss of $10$.

Comment: Oh I see yes I am assuming in my computation that A loses 10 dollars in the situation you described.

Comment: Ah, then that's not the issue.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(Z=j) = \frac{\min\{20,j-1\}}{600}$

Comment: Note:  I get $8.15$ by computing the double sum $\frac 1{600}\times \sum_{a=1,b=1}^{a=30,b=20}  F(a,b)$  Where $F(a,b)=a$ if $a>b$ and $F(a,b)=-b$ if $a≤b$.  Your probabilities do not sum to $1$ (as others have remarked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is where you let $i$ run all the way up to $j-1$ even for $j\gt21$; $B$ can’t roll that high. You could have found this error by checking whether the probabilities sum to $1$.

Comment: Ahhhh now I see. Thank you for catching that mistake!